# Grails Hosting on EC2 Amazon Linux Instance

Tags: grails, amazon-ec2, tomcat8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have successfully uploaded and deployed my grails application on amazon elastic beanstalk with Tomcat 8 and Java 8 on linux ec2 and web app is up and running. It works well when doing REST API calls to and from RDS database. I have a api to upload file to the server from mobile app and from web app frontend. When running this grails app in localhost its works great for this api and uploads files successfully to `user.home/{myapplicationDirectory}/somefile` path in my `Windows OS`. But after running this app in elastic beanstalk and trying to upload image from mobile gives NPE as `FileNotFoundException`

```
FileNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [POST] /api/images/add
/usr/share/tomcat8/sdpl/images/260519011919.zip (No such file or directory)
Stacktrace follows:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat8/sdpl/images/260519011919.zip (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
```

I have a service to get application data storage directory with this method

```
 def String getApplicationPath() {
        return System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "images" + File.separator;
    }
```

Comment: Could it be because images directory doesn't exist? Do you create it elsewhere?

Comment: actually  i haven't create any directory. In windows platform web app used to create the directory perfectly without any errors, but in linux as in aws elastic bean stalk instance it thows error of NPE. I suppose if its the problem of home directory structure of linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as I don't see your full application I don't want to be too presumptuous but as you're using AWS Beanstalk you should consider local file storage to always be a temporary storage.  Your server could be terminate and restarted by beanstalk if it stops responding or fails any health checks. 
You have other options available, again I don't know if you considered them and have a good reason for using the local file system so forgive me if that's the case,  though if not, you could use S3 for the storage of images,  then you don't have to worry about disk space, and the images could automatically be then served via AWS's CDN - Cloudfront, thus also reducing load on your app.

Alternatively, when you really want to store these images in the filesystem, you can look at using EFS,  the Elastic File System.  Your EBS instance could mount the filesystem on startup so it will be always available whenever your instance(s) start.

I didn't suggest using a standard EBS volume, as you can only ever attach a volume to a single instance,  if you used EFS, you don't have to worry about space and it can be mounted to multiple instances so is a little more flexible.